# Jax-RS & Hibernate Endpoint isn't properly able to make queries with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jax-rs

I'm having an issue when I call /search endpoint, The try block always throws a null pointer exception, and "not found" is the response.

**/search endpoint**

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.ezcampus.search.hibernate.entity.ClassType;
import org.ezcampus.search.hibernate.entity.Term;
import org.ezcampus.search.hibernate.entity.Word;
import org.ezcampus.search.hibernate.entity.WordDAO;
import org.ezcampus.search.hibernate.util.SessionUtil;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


@Path("/search")
public class Search {
    
    private final ObjectMapper jsonMap = new ObjectMapper();
        
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getRequestBody(
            @QueryParam("search_term") String searchTerm,
            @QueryParam("page") int page,
            @QueryParam("results_per_page") int resultsPerPage
    ) 
    {
       try {
           return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(
                   WordDAO.getWord("12345")
                   ).build();
       } catch (NullPointerException e) {
           return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(
                   "not found"
           ).build();  
       }              
    } 
}
```

It's quite weird since when I call `WordDAO.getWord("12345")` In A random App.java file with main method, I get a string response. This function runs and returns fine...

But when I'm calling the endpoint, it always throws some NullPointerException and ends up responding with the catch block -> `not_found`

```java
import org.ezcampus.search.hibernate.util.SessionUtil;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class WordDAO {

    public static String getWord(String input) {
        
        try (Session session = SessionUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            
            Word existingWord = session.createQuery("FROM Word WHERE word = :entry", Word.class)
                    .setParameter("entry", input).uniqueResult();
            
            return existingWord.toString();
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Session Factory:

```java
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.tinylog.Logger;

public class SessionUtil
{
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.error(e);

                if (registry != null)
                {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown()
    {
        if (registry != null)
        {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```

Main Application Program (Using Jax-RS Jersey)

```java
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Program extends ResourceConfig {

    public Program() {
        GlobalSettings.IS_DEBUG = true;

        ResourceLoader.loadTinyLogConfig();

        Logger.info("{} starting...", GlobalSettings.BRAND_LONG);
        Logger.info("Running as debug: {}", GlobalSettings.IS_DEBUG);

        // Set the package where the resources are located
        packages("org.github.xyz.rest");


    }
}
```

What could be causing this issue?

Update: MVN Dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tinylog</groupId>
            <artifactId>tinylog-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tinylog</groupId>
            <artifactId>tinylog-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
                
               <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <!-- Adding jersey -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
                
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I mean, you're catching and throwing away the `NullPointerException`, so we can't see the stack trace, and can't tell which line of code throws the NPE. That makes the question impossible to answer.